# ng-file-upload. How to configure the location where the file needs to be uploaded

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

Using ng-file-upload.js to upload files. Two questions: To which location the files get uploaded by default and how to change this location?

Comment: Can you show us your code? It's hard to say what's wrong otherwise. their Demo https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/ has some examples. I suggest you look at them.

Comment: If you mean the location on the server side then that is not client/angular side so it needs to be configured on your server.

Answer (score 1):

From github documentation (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

```
var upload = Upload.upload({
  url: 'server/upload/url', // upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
...
```

> Alternative way of uploading, send the file binary with the file's content-type.
>      Could be used to upload files to CouchDB, imgur, etc... html5 FileReader is needed.
>      It could also be used to enable progress for regualr angular $http() post/put requests.

```
var uploadHttp = Upload.http({
  url: '/server/upload/url',
  ...
```

Comment: url: 'server/upload/url', : Is this the location to which the files need to be uploaded?

Comment: Looks like that is to receive the data!

Comment: In "url" you need to specify the location where you want your files uploaded. It works for upload, that's why it uses "Upload" service.